# Finding the range of $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x+\sin x-1}{\sin^2x-\sin x+2}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am attempting to find the range of the function $f\mapsto \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ which is given by the expression as follows.

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x+\sin x-1}{\sin^2x-\sin x+2}$$

This is rational function in $\sin x$, so it will be periodic. Usually when there is a rational function with quadratic expressions, differentiation can be used or, $x$ is rewritten in terms of $y$, so that gives.

$$\sin x=\frac{(y+1)\pm\sqrt{10-2y-3y^2}}{2(y-1)}\in[-1,1]$$

This is a tedious task and so is using differentiation to find minima and maxima. Any hints to go about this problem using a different technique are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$\varphi(x)=\frac{x^2+x-1}{x^2-x+2};$$then $f=\varphi\circ\sin$. Since the range of $\sin$ is $[-1,1]$, the range of $f$ is $\varphi\bigl([-1,1]\bigr)$. But $\varphi$ is stricly decreasing on $\left[-1,\frac{3-\sqrt{11}}2\right]$ and strictly increasing on $\left[\frac{3-\sqrt{11}}2,1\right]$. Since,

- $f(-1)=-\frac14$;
- $f\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{11}}2\right)=\frac{3-2\sqrt{11}}7$;
- $f(1)=\frac12$,

the range is $\left[\frac{3-2\sqrt{11}}7,\frac12\right]$.